# Можно ли использовать двоеточие, вопросительный знак в скобках?

Tags: пунктуация, вставная-конструкция

Я имею в виду не только знаки в скобках, но и их сочетание с текстом, который стоит в скобках.
Приведите примеры, желательно из литературы (отдельно для двоеточия и вопроса).

Например:

> Это были годные примеры, говорящие сами за себя (о годноте: согласно оценкам не хуже тех знаменитых от июля 2017 г.!). Поэтому, мы решили...

Можно так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) выделяются скобками или тире. Они содержат дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки к сказанному; разъясняют, толкуют основную часть высказывания.
**В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки (запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие)**:
*Стараясь не показать виду и собрав для этого всю выдержку (ведь неизвестно, что за люди!), лесник пригласил нас в дом* (Сол.).
[Знаки препинания при вставках](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128)

Вот некоторые примеры из одного произведения.

1. В последний раз на телевидении она играла в «Несчастном случае» — обаятельную бабушку, которая в войну была зенитчицей, а умерла от переохлаждения в многоэтажке, отчего другие персонажи обильно заламывали руки (Как это могло случиться в наши дни? Эта женщина защищала свою страну. И так далее).
2. Имя («Винс, Винс, — бормотал режиссер, — неужели трудно запомнить?») от нее ускользало. Забралось в мозг и там потерялось.
3. Она думала, что ее наняли до упора («Моя пенсия», — блаженно бубнила она над третьей «Звездочкой»), а на той неделе сказали, что контракт не продлят и в конце сезона она умрет.
4. Началось с невиннейшей просьбы (Я хотела спросить: вы не могли бы что-нибудь выяснить о моих биологических родителях?) и завело в лабиринт, куда ни ткнешься — тупик.
   [К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоём](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/1013421/Atkinson_-_Chut_svet%2C_s_sobakoyu_vdvoem.html)

**Дополнение**
Предложение, приведенное Вами, нуждается в поправках.
1. Вместо "о годноте" ([**годнота**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) — *жарг.* нечто толковое и хорошего качества) лучше использовать "о годности".
2. *(...от июля 2017 г.!)* — такое оформление не совсем корректно, визуально плохо воспринимается на стыке со скобкой. Лучше так: от июля 2017 года! Или: от июля 2017!
3. Запятая после "поэтому" не нужна.

Я бы оформила так:
Это были годные примеры, говорящие сами за себя (о годности: согласно оценкам — не хуже тех знаменитых от июля 2017!), поэтому мы решили...

Answer (score 2):

С помощью скобок выделяются вставные конструкции. В тексте вставной конструкции сохраняются все необходимые для нее знаки (запятая, восклицательный и вопросительный знаки, многоточие, двоеточие.

> Ср.: Подкараулил этого кота гражданин в тот момент, когда животное с вороватым видом (что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид **?** Это не оттого, что они порочны, а оттого, что они боятся, чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они — собаки и люди **—** не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то и другое очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да, нет никакой **!**), да, так с вороватым видом кот собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи (Булг.).

…Быть может (**лестная надежда!**), укажет будущий невежда на мой прославленный портрет… (П.)/

Мы узнали от него самого, что он, г. Савельев, решился посвятить все способности (чьи?) разработанию **(разрабатыванию?)** отечественной истории (Бел.);
Он чуть свет был уже на дворе, как ни в чём не бывало, сохраняя далее **(невинная хитрость!)** прежнюю унылость на лице(Т.).

**См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской 
орфографии и пунктуации. 
Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография и пунктуация.**